# How to populate table values dynamically based on JSON in datatable angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I'm using [Angular-Datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/). I need to be able to dynamically create the table based on the data that is being returned. In other words, I do not want to specify the column headers.

**Example:**

json data:

```
[
 {
  "id": "2",
  "city": "Baltimore",
  "state": "MD",
 },
 {
  "id": "5",
  "city": "Boston",
  "state": "MA",
 },
 {
  "id": "8",
  "city": "Malvern",
  "state": "PA",
 },
]
```

Column Headers:

id, city, state

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Specifying column headers are awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is actually a good question! With traditional jQuery dataTables it is not a problem, but we have a different kind of declarative setup with angular dataTables, making it more difficult to separate the various tasks. We can delay the population of data with `fromFnPromise`, but not prevent the dataTable from being instantiated before we want it. I think I have found a solid solution :

First, to avoid instant initialization remove the `datatable` directive from the markup and give the `<table>` an `id` instead, i.e :

```
<table id="example" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" />
```

Then load the data resource, build `dtColumns` and `dtOptions` and finally inject the `datatable` attribute and `$compile` the `<table>` using the `id` :

```
$http({
  url: 'data.json'
}).success(function(data) {
  var sample = data[0], dtColumns = []

  //create columns based on first row in dataset
  for (var key in sample) dtColumns.push(
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle(key)
  )
  $scope.dtColumns = dtColumns

  //create options
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('data', data)
    .withOption('dataSrc', '')

  //initialize the dataTable
  angular.element('#example').attr('datatable', '')
  $compile(angular.element('#example'))($scope)
})
```

This should work with any "array of objects" resource
Demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/TzBaaZ2Msd9WchfLDLkN?p=preview**

---

NB: Have cleaned up the example JSON, I guess it was a sample and not meant to be working with trailing commas.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely makes sense. I'll implement the solution on my side and update this as an accepted answer thereafter. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sana, Thank you for taking notice. Have fixed the plunkr. It did not work because the author of Angular DataTables for some reason decided to  build AD for angular 2/4/5 on top of the existing branch, so any references without specific version does no longer work :(

Comment: Any idea how to do it with nested JSON objects

Answer (score 5):

Being faced with the same problem, I actually found an easier to implement and much simpler (and safer because of not using $compile) solution.

The only change needed to be made to the html is the addition of an `ng-if`:

```
<table ng-if="columnsReady" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"/>
```

What happens is that angular will delay the creation of this node till `columnsReady` has any value. So now in your code you can get the data you need, and when you have it, you can just set `columnsReady` to `true` and angular will do the rest.

```
$http({
  url: 'data.json'
}).success(function(data) {
  var sample = data[0], dtColumns = []

  //create columns based on first row in dataset
  for (var key in sample) dtColumns.push(
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(key).withTitle(key)
  )
  $scope.dtColumns = dtColumns

  //create options
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('data', data)
    .withOption('dataSrc', '')

  //initialize the dataTable
  $scope.columnsReady = true;
});
```

Comment: great solution.

Comment: This helped me immensely trying to implement loading 'fromFnPromise". Putting a Datatables into a uib-tab the promise was always being fetched on page load. Hiding the table in non-visible tabs with "ng-if" and then toggling the boolean works a treat. Many thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Below code which will give you table dynamically based on data

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="WithAjaxCtrl as showCase">
<table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('showcase.withAjax',['datatables']).controller('WithAjaxCtrl', WithAjaxCtrl);

function WithAjaxCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
var vm = this;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('city').withTitle('City'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('state').withTitle('State')
];
```

}

**data.json**

```
[{
"id": 860,
"city": "Superman",
"state": "Yoda"
}, {
"id": 870,
"city": "Foo",
"state": "Whateveryournameis"
}, {
"id": 590,
"city": "Toto",
"state": "Titi"
}, {
"id": 803,
"city": "Luke",
"state": "Kyle"
 },
 ...
 ]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I do not want to have to specify the column headers with vm.dtColumns